# Comment in Qgis project

Tags: qgis

How do I add a comment in a project in QGIS like Klas Karlsson did in his youtube explanation about MGRS https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlOx_E-odg8  at around 8min. ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS, go to `View` > `Decorations` > `Title Label`.